# Windows could not start the Apache2.4 service. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I just put my PC on this morning and I get the following error when starting Apache2.4 from Services:

> Windows could not start the Apache2.4 service on Local Computer. 
> Error
>   1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

I went on Event Viewer to check the logs as most people were suggesting this online and that was no help either, see below screenshot of the error log:

[image]

This doesn't really point to the problem or say what the actual problem is, so my question  is how can I find the actual cause of Apache not working?